# ToolbarItem is not showing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbar, toolbaritems

Im currently reading trough [this book](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2016/03/31/free-ebook-creating-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms/).

Already at the beginning of the book I have a problem. I have `Primary` ToolbarItems and `Secondary` ToolbarItems. But none of them are shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BookCode" 
             x:Class="BookCode.MainPage"
             Title="Visuals">


    <StackLayout Padding="10,0">
        <Label Text="Hello, Xamarin.Forms!"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Button Text="Click Me!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Switch VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="edit" Order="Primary">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                            iOS="edit.png"
                            Android="ic_action_edit.png"
                            WinPhone="Images/edit.png"/>

            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="search" Order="Primary">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                            iOS="search.png"
                            Android="ic_action_search.png"
                            WinPhone="Images/feature.search.png"/>
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>

        <ToolbarItem Text="refresh" Order="Primary">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                            iOS="reload.png"
                            Android="ic_action_refresh.png"
                            WinPhone="Images/refresh.png"/>
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>

        <ToolbarItem Text="explore" Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="discover" Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="evolve" Order="Secondary" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Where do you have the images for the icons stored? Are you seeing the same result when adding `ToolbarItem`s in C#?

Comment: Ohh. I see. I just assumed the images were there by standard since they are not really mentioned to pasted somehwere. But one thing I still dont understand, the ToolbarItems with 'Order="Secondary"' are not shown. They don´t use any Images. Where are they?

Comment: No, `Secondary` items do not have icons. They are displayed as text-only. As an FYI, they'll work better on Android than iOS, as iOS doesn't typically allow secondary toolbar items. On Android, you'll have a toolbar item extension (three dots), but iOS will just accumulate them on the toolbar. You will have to add your won images to the respective resource directories for each platform.

Comment: So I took a look in the "Resources" Folder of BookCode.iOS and found a few .png files. I replaced the images to Default.png (example: edit.png to Default.png). Images are still not shown. I thought maybe its width/height were too high so I downloaded a 25x25 image, pasted it in the "Resources" folder, changed Default.png to a.png (the 25x25 image) and tried it again. Still no ToolbarItem :(

Comment: Have you tried without icons? The text should still appear. Alternatively, move you `ContentPage.ToolbarItems` above you `StackLayout`.

Comment: Yes I tried it without icons. Nothing changed. I tried to put ContentPage.ToolbarItems above the StackLayout. Also nothing changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ToolbarItems` needs a Navigation Page to show them up. So modify MainPage wrapped by a navigation page:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Comment: Hi mate, just a question, where do you add this line? I am in the same situation where I got the code for ContentPage.ToolbarItems but the Toolbar is not showing up. Thanks.

Comment: An important note is that ToolbarItems will not show up if you are calling it in a modal. Make sure the page you are displaying is not a modal.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="edit" Order="Primary">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                        Android="icon.png"/>

        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="search" Order="Primary">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                       Android="icon.png"/>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>

    <ToolbarItem Text="refresh" Order="Primary">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                        Android="icon.png"/>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>

    <ToolbarItem Text="explore" Order="Secondary"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="discover" Order="Secondary"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="evolve" Order="Secondary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,0">
        <Label Text="Hello, Xamarin.Forms!"
           FontSize="Large"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Button Text="Click Me!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Switch VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: I copied your code and changed "Android="icon.png"" to "iOS="Default.png"". I just cant see those ToolbarItem s - https://imgur.com/a/9weMdxQ

Comment: Don't change, just add iOS. And i just showed you the running code on Android. See if you have this picture in iOS project.

Comment: This time I copied your code and added iOS. I still cant see the ToolbarItems :(

Comment: Check whether the image is in the iOS project or not.

Comment: @Wasif Mahmood Mustafa : If you could tell me in WHICH android folder I have to look for "icon.png", there are so many..... For me too, only text, no icon (is in drawable)

Comment: @Martin Drawable folder where you put all your icons.